# Why am I receiving MSVCR100 missing again and again when I run 3d max?

Tags: 3d, max, autodesk

I recently installed 3D Max for Cartoon like animation work but I am not sure if my graphic card is okay for this it is Quadroo 2000 but i'm getting this msvcr200.dll missing error. :( HELP ANYONE?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-performance/msvcp100dll-missing/9a687c31-0619-4ee9-b511-020985e29b5f

Answer (score 1):

Short answer your software is missing a dependency, more exactly the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package**.
The best course of action is to download and install the said package from a trusted source.

After a little google-ing I've found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52f0bd37-9a08-41b6-bb43-fa01ef3ebc4a/msvcr100dll-is-missing?forum=w8itprogeneral) post on Microsoft's technet forum, that points to:
**32Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

**64Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

You should download the one needed for your software. If you are on a x64 architecture, it would be a safer bet to just download&install both of them.